# Determine whether the argument is valid or invalid

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$\;(\lnot p \lor q)\land (\lnot p \rightarrow q)$
$\;\;\;\;p$
$\overline{\therefore\;\lnot q\qquad}$

Valid or invalid: How would I approach this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first premise (left hand side) is equivalent to the right hand side. Why?:
$$(\lnot p \lor q)\land (\lnot p \rightarrow q) \equiv (p \rightarrow q) \land (\lnot p \rightarrow q)$$

Now, you have a second premise: $\quad p$.

By simplification, and then modus ponens, we have

$$p\rightarrow q$$
$$p$$
$$\therefore \quad q$$

is a valid argument. But do you have any justification for concluding $\lnot q$?

Comment: So it's invalid?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it's invalid.

Comment: @ amWhy can you please show me with another example? Ie : p -> q  [nextline] q -> ~r [nextline] r  [nextline] ∴ ~p

Comment: Can you see how from $p \rightarrow q, \;q \rightarrow \lnot r$ we can conclude $p \rightarrow \lnot r$? Note also that: $r \equiv \lnot (\lnot r)$. So you have $p \rightarrow \lnot r$ and $\lnot(\lnot r)$, and by modus tollens, we *can* infer the valid conclusion: $ \lnot p$

Comment: Yes. So ~p would be a valid statement ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Be sure you understand that why the statement $\lnot p$ is a valid conclusion.

Comment: I think I kind of understand

Comment: I understand now because $p \rightarrow q

Comment: @amWhy: Nice interchange + 1

Answer (score 2):

Assume that:

$$p\equiv T,~q\equiv T$$ so we have $$\sim p\vee q\equiv T,~~\sim p\to q\equiv T,~~ \big((\sim p\vee q)\wedge (\sim p\to q)\big)\wedge p\equiv T\wedge T\equiv T$$

Comment: Nice approach, @Babak (+1). ;-)

Comment: Where is my dear friend? You must be very busy right now...I miss your posts :(

Comment: @amWhy: Hello my dear Amy. Honestly, I was not on a good mood. Whenever I feel like this, I sit and just look at the page and questions. Moreover, lots of the questions were related to some special fields out of my knowledge. I hope you are feeling good inside. :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual "follow your nose" approach is to first translate everything into ANDs, ORs and NOTs.  So change the implication from $\neg p\rightarrow q$ to $p \vee q$ and you obtain $(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee q)$.  Now plug in that $p$ is true which means the 2nd clause is true and you just need to focus on $(\neg p \vee q)$.  But what happens if $p$ is true in this clause?  What must $q$ be?